# How to push changes of node app to Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I watches a lot a tutorials but still don't know how to update my code in EC2 instance without 100 steps. In every tutorial they uploading files with filezilla but I'm updating my node app code several time a day and opening filezilla, dragging files, opening ssh connection and restarting app every time is frustrating, I hope there is a way to push code with single command or something.

Comment: You can use elastic beanstalk with code pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

There is, use git (push from dev machine, pull from ec2 instance then restart app) or simpler use git with CI/CD (requires some study though).

Comment: I tried using CodeCommit, CodeDeploy and CodePipeline. but codepipeline fails in codedeploy stage every time with unclear error message: "The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems."

Answer (score 0):

Simply, You can push your code in Git and pull that code from inside the EC2 instance.

For automated deployment, You can use Git and AWS CodeDeploy to update the EC2 code change in one step.

For reference:

https://hackernoon.com/continuous-deployment-with-aws-codedeploy-github-d1eb97550b82 (Step by step guide)

https://github.com/azat-co/codedeploy-codepipeline-node (sample github code for codedeploy with aws)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS developer tools (CodeCommit, CodeDeploy, and CodePipeline) for this.

PS. For codedeploy, you've to make sure that you've successfully installed the codedeploy agent on your web server.